# iOS 10 Xcode 8 - migration to Swift 3 and Date

Tags: ios, swift, exception, swift3

I'm in the process of migration an iOS app from swift 2 to swift 3 and I encounter this error that I don't understand and I'm not sure what to do.

The issue occurs when I try to read the property called `dateApproved` but not for `dateCreated`.

```
print("dateApproved: \(cEntity.dateApproved)")
print("dateCreated: \(cEntity.dateCreated)")
```

**Entity class**

```
@objc(entity)
open class Entity: NSManagedObject {

    ...
    @NSManaged var dateApproved: Date
    @NSManaged var dateCreated: Date
    ...
```

Upon inspecting the property cEntity I can see that

```
dateApproved = nil;
dateCreated = "2016-08-24 22:20:38 +0000";
```

This is a screenshot of the error

[image]

Note: it worked before, it just doesn't work anymore since I'm migrated all the code to make it compliant with Swift 3.

Could you please give me some pointers about how to solve/track this issue. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance variable `dateApproved` is declared as a non-optional variable, i.e. Swift will assume it's never *nil*. However, as the debugger shows, it is *nil*.

Therfore, change the declaration to match reality and make it optional.

```
@NSManaged var dateApproved: Date?
```

Comment: It was indeed the problem. Thanks